# reading matrix from a stdin txt file in c

Tags: c, matrix, stdin, txt

I've got an assignment which I have 4 hours to do and I just can't continue.

There are 3 different text files, each has different matrices with different data types and different row and column numbers.

And we have to input the .txt file with command line such as:
./pe6 < input1.txt

Inputs

```
input1.txt:
 16,  11,  10,  16,  24,  40,  51,  61,
 12,  12,  14,  19,  26,  58,  60,  55,
 14,  13,  16,  24,  40,  57,  69,  56,
 14,  17,  22,  29,  51,  87,  80,  62,
 18,  22,  37,  56,  68, 109, 103,  77,
 24,  35,  55,  64,  81, 104, 113,  92,
 49,  64,  78,  87, 103, 121, 120, 101,
 72,  92,  95,  98, 112, 100, 103,  99
```

```
input3.txt:
19.996,-13.479,6.8042,-0.86667,-0.2625,-3.0167,-7.3708,-0.49583,-4.8,-4.1875,-0.91667,2.3917,2.2125,7.7958,-5.3708,0.36667
-13.479,24.496,-4.7208,2.3333,-10.321,-8.1833,5.4208,-7.7542,9.3333,6.1042,5.5167,0.84167,-2.6958,-13.146,-0.5125,-5.3
6.8042,-4.7208,27.863,3.6667,-3.7375,-7.5833,-0.9625,-8.7042,-4.8,-10.146,9.65,3.675,-1.9458,10.271,-2.2958,2.6333
-0.86667,2.3333,3.6667,21.867,-12.6,-2.2,3.2667,-3.4667,3.4,1.2667,-7,10.867,-4.8,0.13333,4.6,5.8667
-0.2625,-10.321,-3.7375,-12.6,20.929,7.6167,-5.8292,7.0292,-5.6,-2.9458,-5.75,-10.992,7.8542,0.9375,-0.029167,-0.16667
-3.0167,-8.1833,-7.5833,-2.2,7.6167,23.8,6.5833,2.0833,0.33333,0.78333,-2.0667,-9.5,-3.6167,5.45,-2.0833,3.3333
-7.3708,5.4208,-0.9625,3.2667,-5.8292,6.5833,22.996,1.9375,10,3.5125,-4.5833,-1.675,-4.5542,2.0292,-1.8708,5.3
-0.49583,-7.7542,-8.7042,-3.4667,7.0292,2.0833,1.9375,19.929,-1,-0.44583,-11.083,-0.125,3.1542,-3.0958,4.2708,0.5
-4.8,9.3333,-4.8,3.4,-5.6,0.33333,10,-1,19.733,4.7333,0.66667,3.8,1.4667,-4.8,0.2,1.2667
-4.1875,6.1042,-10.146,1.2667,-2.9458,0.78333,3.5125,-0.44583,4.7333,14.896,-4.1167,-0.44167,0.1625,-5.8542,4.3125,5.9667
-0.91667,5.5167,9.65,-7,-5.75,-2.0667,-4.5833,-11.083,0.66667,-4.1167,24.333,-3.1667,-7.85,3.75,-8.45,-5.7333
2.3917,0.84167,3.675,10.867,-10.992,-9.5,-1.675,-0.125,3.8,-0.44167,-3.1667,23.85,2.7583,-0.675,14.525,-1.2
2.2125,-2.6958,-1.9458,-4.8,7.8542,-3.6167,-4.5542,3.1542,1.4667,0.1625,-7.85,2.7583,15.562,-4.1875,8.9792,-3.3667
7.7958,-13.146,10.271,0.13333,0.9375,5.45,2.0292,-3.0958,-4.8,-5.8542,3.75,-0.675,-4.1875,17.462,-6.9708,5.5667
-5.3708,-0.5125,-2.2958,4.6,-0.029167,-2.0833,-1.8708,4.2708,0.2,4.3125,-8.45,14.525,8.9792,-6.9708,24.196,0.23333
0.36667,-5.3,2.6333,5.8667,-0.16667,3.3333,5.3,0.5,1.2667,5.9667,-5.7333,-1.2,-3.3667,5.5667,0.23333,16.267
```

First function has to read the file and return a matrix, row and column numbers.

Firstly I just tried to accumulate all the values inside a 1d array just to see if I can read them all. The prog was working but I did something I don't know what I did wrong (maybe deleted some lines I can't see it) but it's not reading after first value anymore. I've been staring at my code for soo long, I have to write functions doing multiplication, transpose etc after that, so I could use some help.

```
  3 int readMatrix(){ // read matrix from txt, return matrix, nrows, ncols
  4     double input[100];
  5     int i;
  6
  7     while( scanf("%lf", &input[i]) != EOF ){ // read untill EOF
  8
  9         scanf("%lf", &input[i]); // read the value
 10         printf("%.2lf \n", input[i]); // check if it's reading
 11
 12         i+=1; // implement loop var
 13
 14         if(i>64){break;} // try with 8x8 
 15     }
 16     return 0;
 17 }
```

Output:

```
$ ./pe6 < input1.txt
16.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

Also I have no idea how I will detect the column and row changes of different matrices with same function, and I'm not %100 sure about memory allocation for matrix with unknown number of rows and columns, tbh I couldn't find so much on internet. I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: By column numbers, do you mean individual lines make up one column? This format is terrible for reading, as `scanf` `" "` is any number of whitespace characters without determining which. As a hack, you could get the line with `fgets`, and then `sscanf` with "%lf%c " and check the return or %c is ','. Or is it always going to to 8x8?

Comment: Well the assignment requires to read the file with i/o redirection, I don't know if fgets works with stdin input, does it? As I checked the example source codes the professor uploaded, he mostly used scanf. I have 3 different input files, input1 and 2 has 8x8 matrices in it and input3 has 16x16 one. The function has to be able to read each, derive the values to an 2d arrays with proper nrows and ncols.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't delineate between different white-spaces; if they are _square_, you could easily do it with `scanf`, just take the square-root and ignore new-lines (this is more robust.) `fgets` does work with `stdin`; in fact `scanf` is just `fscanf` with `stdin`. But check the docs, there are 3 returns from `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are reading twice each times : once in the condition of the while and a second time inside the body of the loop. The second `scanf` can be omitted.

Then in the input the numbers are separated by commas, so the `scanf` format should be `"%lf,"`.

Finally you should initialize your `i` index to 0, you never know.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it and it succesfully read  the input1.txt but when it comes to read negative floating numbers in input3.txt the output end with wrong numbers:

last 6 output of : $ ./pe6 < input3.txt





10.87
-4.80
0.13
4.60
5.87
-0.26

Comment: Forget it mate I just figured out I am the reason of it lol. I put <64 limit so it's not printing until the end. I would appreciate if you have any ideas how I can deal with different nrows and ncols while reading and creating a matrix out of these. I instantly get SegFault if I delete the <64 limit. EOF tactic seems to be not working.